# java thinks new files are folders

Tags: java, file

My java program keeps thinking that every new file is not a file but a folder.

I have been bug hunting and now it will not let me save a file using `FileWriter`. If I create a new File, and then check if it is a file or a directory, it says it is a directory.

I originally had a long path that was created, so I got rid of that. I also used to have the writing done in a separate thread, and got rid of that as well, but still the problem persists.

If I create a new class, with just a simple

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("test.csv");
output.print(file.isDirectory());
```

This comes out as true.

I can however still save graphics using javax.imageio.*

Can anyone help?

Edit: I am using eclispe 3.7.2 with java 1.7.0...
File.isFile() is false, File.createNewFile() fails (java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is Denied)). When looking in the directory I specify, there is a new folder there called test.csv. So it is creating a new folder, and is treating it as a folder, despite the fact that I am specifying it is a csv file. I have tried other file types, even no file type. But the same problem. It thinks it is a folder and not a file. This is just baffling me.

Comment: Please help us with the env- JDK, JRE, OS etc

Comment: If Java says it's a directory, it's a directory. What evidence do you have that it isn't?

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("test.csv");
    System.err.println(file.isDirectory()); // prints false
    System.err.println(file.isFile()); // prints false
    System.err.println(file.exists()); // prints false
  }`

Comment: There is no directory or file. I am creating a new one. But whether I use FileWriter(String), FileWriter(File) or File.createNewFile() all of them just create a new folder named my filename (eg test.csv) and then fail to write anything to it (giving a java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied)) because it is trying to write to the newly created folder, when I wanted a file. So you are correct. It is a folder (newly created) but I want a file, not a folder!

Comment: So, what you found yourself is what I told you from the start: you create directory(ies) using FULL PATH before you attempt to write to the file and then you FAIL to handle the error attempting to write to the file (you can NOT have duplicate named objects [even of different types] in the directory)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java's `new File()` does **NOT** create files or directories by itself. So you should show your code that does. I suspect that you have something like `file.mkdirs();` somewhere - if your `file` is referring to "test.csv" at this point it **will** create a directory called "test.csv"

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: when creating a new file, by using FileWriter(File) it fails with a java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is Denied) (though I know I have permission to write there). But once this has run, if I go to the directory (whichever dir I specify in the path) there is a new folder called my filename (eg test1.csv). If I use File.createNewFile() it creates a new folder named that filename. It just cannot create a new file for some reason!

Comment: So, what you found yourself is what I told you from the start: you create directory(ies) using **FULL PATH** before you attempt to write to the file and then you **FAIL** to handle the error attempting to write to the file (you can **NOT** have duplicate named objects [even of different types] in the directory)

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code, you haven't actually *created* the file yet. For our entertainment, can you also print the value of `file.isFile()`?

Then do the same, but call e.g. `file.createNewFile()` *first*, to actually get the file.

Comment: @lbalazscs Indeed, there's still the chance that somehow a directory with that name got created first, but that would really be an accident in the setup, then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missign something, maby you have a directory wehre you programm is located which is called the same as the file you are trying to create, you can test this using either the [isFile()](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29) Function to make sure its not a file and try to get the Path using  [getAbsolutePath()](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) to localize where this Directory is set.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. As expected it was my own stupidity, as I knew it must be. I had moved the File.mkdirs() method after I added the filename to the file path, making the full path, including the file, a directory. Then I could not write to it, because it was already created as a directory.

I could have sworn I tested it without the mkdirs() command but I guess not. Oh well. Scratch one more up to stupidity and not properly removing all possible options.

Thanks for all the tips!

Comment: Remember to eventually accept an answer, even if it is your own-that's okay.

Comment: @Darkraiyy Re-read my original answer - this is EXACTLY what I told you